# Overwrite the data in a data frame through looping, but it does not store the changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to add a few characters to certain cells in the `dataframe`. When I print `xx` in the loop, the values are as desired. But when I print the entire `dataframe`, the values were unchanged:

```
for row in df['Time from AtoC']:
    if ':' not in row:
        xx = "00:" + row
#         print(xx)
        df.at['Time from AtoC'] = xx

    else:
        df.at['Time from AtoC'] = row
```

**The results I get are**

> 179 rows of data when I only had 100, and some of the values remained
>   unchanged (without 00: in front).

Comment: post sample data and expected output

Comment: And avoid looping over dataframe or column. There are alternatives available in `pandas`

Comment: check with `df['Time from AtoC']=np.where(df['Time from AtoC'].str.contains(':'),"00:"+df['Time from AtoC'],df['Time from AtoC'])` also check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to add 00 to the front of your times (that are strings) if they are not there? You can put your decision logic in a function and then apply it to the column all at once. (As a bonus, you could do this all in one line with an anonymous function (lambda).

```
def add_00(time):
   if ':' not in time:
       return "00:" + time
   return time

df['Time from AtoC'] = df['Time from AtoC'].apply(add_00)
```